# Why don't Threejs.org examples run on my computer anymore?

Tags: three.js, webgl, gpu, hardware, video-card

My computer's hardware is no longer compatible with some newer webGL stuff, including many Three.js examples as well as webcam streaming. Can anyone explain why this is? I'd love to learn more about how the gaphics card works, if it is related to that.

- it's not a browser issue
- it's not an https:// issue
- the examples in 3js that do not work are: - any PlaneGeometry does not show up, [hemi lighting demo](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=hem#webgl_lights_hemisphere) shows up all white , [lookAt demo](https://threejs.org/examples/#misc_lookat) shows up almost entirely white

My specs:
[image]

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the javascript/web console? Is this something that just started happening recently? Did you recently upgrade to El Capitan?

Comment: what does `about:gpu` say in chrome?

Comment: I am trying to see the `about:gpu` log but not sure how. I tried entering into terminal `--enable-gpu-client-logging` but got `-bash: --enable-gpu-client-logging: command not found` Any further advice is much appreciated! I also asked about it on the chromium group to see if they can walk me through it.

Comment: Update! The console tells me this: `three.js:16616 THREE.WebGLProgram: gl.getProgramInfoLog() WARNING: Could not find vertex shader attribute 'position' to match BindAttributeLocation request.`

Comment: Do you have 'Automatic graphics switching' enabled? (System Preferences > Energy Saver). It seems you're using Chrome: do you have the same issues if using Safari or Firefox? Searching Google for your GPU model seems to pull up a lot of discussion regarding odd behavior regarding Chrome, WebGL, and AMD Radeon HD 6770M -- perhaps related. It could also be related to a browser extension you have installed. Hard to diagnose without more information.